# Either workflow or automation solution to pull shipment data from a PDF with multiple shipments

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat

**What I Have / Background on Workflow**

Every day we receive a scanned PDF consolidating all shipments out of a warehouse for the prior day. The PDF pages are ordered by shipment.

Number of pages for each shipment varies based on multiple factors (certificates, taxes, customs, etc...), however there are 2-3 page types that follow roughly identically formatting across shipments.

Each location ID for each shipment has its own page, and these pages follow roughly identical formatting across SKU/shipment number - the right-hand side has a table with a row for each individual item pulled from that location.
**I want to pull these SKU numbers to be able to compare them to the ones we have logged in our system**

If the document has a certificate, then the locationID page will have an additional column in the table, indicating a dollar amount rebate.

I have experience with Python and Excel, and just got an Adobe License, so have access to the full feature set of Adobe Acrobat.

**What I'm looking for**

Every day I have to go through this PDF, confirm that the inventory was pulled from the correct location, and to update the rebate amount from a quote we have in our system to the actual dollar amount, which is determined from the PDF

Given this forum is for powerusers, I'm wondering if anyone could offer guidance on workflow or potential automation solutions so that I'm not scrolling between multiple pages for each shipment. The ideal output for me would be a csv like below, but I have no clue if it's feasible:

| Shipment | Location | Rebate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | $100 |
| ABC | 345 | $150 |
| XYZ | 123 | $0 |
| LMN | 345 | $200 |

My current workflow is going through and bookmarking the first page of each shipment in the PDF, I then follow along a system-generated list of orders that our Operations Team marked as shipped, and go to the corresponding bookmark for each.

Any pointers in the right direction would be hugely appreciated! I think the place to start is trying to find a way to exclusively pull or separate the locationID tables.

I don't care too much about misreading characters, as Location ID numbers are distinct enough; and given that it is my job, I can estimate rebate amounts mentally.

Comment: @Martin Goni ,,, convert the PDF into EXCEL Data Sheet, then U may go for corrections easily ,,,,   or by using Power Query Data updates based location is also possible.

Comment: Is the PDF generated from an electronic original and contains selectable text, or is it more like a scanned in series of pages, each page being an image of a page of text? If it's the former, then Power Query and a load of patience could be the best way I say patience, because you will need to work out how to deal with all the stuff you *don't* want, get rid of filler rows that don't represent data, page footers, unwanted repeated headings etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a business document, *particularly* one having financial implications, "page types that follow **roughly** identically formatting," *is not good enough*.  A PDF document is meant to provide a specific **appearance** on the page, but does not guarantee particular characters are used to do so.

As just one example, rather than containing `finance`, a document might have `ﬁnance`. What's the difference? the first has separate letters "f" and "i", while the second uses the [single Unicode ligature "ﬁ"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FB01). Automatic parsing of a PDF document to extract data is *risky*.

**If** you're willing to take that risk, and **if** you'd check results on every file conversion, you might try OCR to first change the PDF to straight text -- and expect OCR errors.

It would be far more sensible to change operations *at the beginning* by using a standardized format that can easily be parsed, such as a spreadsheet, CSV, database file, or *perhaps* a standardized Adobe **form** where only specific fields can be entered.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change things outside of my role; the warehouse isn't owned by us, so we get what we get. Accuracy isn't something I'm particularly worried about within the scope of the question - that's a separate constraint that I will be able to manage. Do you know if Adobe has the capacity to use OCR to auto-generate bookmarks? Rather than pulling data, I'd be able to cut down on pages that aren't relevant to my use of the documents, and preserve accuracy.

Comment: I don't know how much machine learning has improved in the 3 years since I last tried pdf automation for invoices. Hopefully by leaps and bounds so that your task is simpler. If not, then I echo the answer to communicate with whoever is sending you the "scanned" pdf document to see what they are doing. Maybe they have an underlying process of taking an excel file and are taking screenshots and compling it into a pdf file for you.

Comment: If you have to start with the scanned pdf file, then I suggest you start with the adobe acrobat's built in ocr functions.  Where you go from there is dependent on how the OCR is converting the data. I think the other nearly free option is to use MicroSoft Power Apps, but I wouldn't have recommended it 3 years ago...